# Why does adding a solution folder in Visual Studio change project files, and is there any way to prevent this?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution-folders

I am adding a test project to many solutions in our project's primary git repository.

In the process, I noticed that adding a "Solution Folder" to the .sln file modifies many of the projects in the solution.  I can think of no logical reason this would be the case.  I am *only* talking about adding the solution file, *before* I add the test project.

All of the projects in the solution are C# projects, if that would make any difference.

Does anybody know why this is the case.  Is this intended behavior, or a bug?  Also, is there any way to prevent this from happening?

The two images below highlight the behavior I am talking about:

**Before adding the new solution folder**:

[image: Before adding solution folder. No project changes.]

**After adding the new solution folder**:

[image: After adding solution folder. Project files have changed.]

**As far as I can tell, the changes are meaningless**:

[image: The project files changes are meaningless.]

Comment: Looks like the folders and projects have different casing than specified in the Solution file.

Comment: If it is corrected, all projects referencing that project get updated project references. Best thing to do is to fix the case issues once and for all.

Comment: @jessehouwing - My prior (deleted) comment was wrong.  All of the changes appear to be casing-related.  Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes.  If you submit an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @jessehouwing - the behavior appears to be non-determistic.  Depending on which solution I have open, sometimes the in project references is corrected in the references project, and sometimes it is not.  If I open the master solution with all our projects and do this, only ONE project file is updated.  So strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit weird, but these things happen when people have multiple solutions and fix the casing in one Solution, but not the other. When the project file is re-rendered (because a project is added, renamed, solution item changed etc), then it will pick up the corrected casing. If the solution file has the 'correct' casing, nothing may change, but if the solution file mismatches it can cause this cascade.

Fixing the casing in one solution may trigger the reverse behavior in another solution. Hence, this must be fixed in all solution files at once. Be careful if you have multiple branches.

The best way to fix this is to fix the casing issues on the file system, project files and solution files in a single go. Doing it with a text editor is usually easier than through the Visual Studio project system. Regex search&replace can do wonders here. Make sure you fix all of these at once:

- The contents of (all of) the solution file(s)
- The `.*proj` file causing the problem
- The file system path (you may have to change more than the case first for the case change to take). Also make sure your Version Control system will take the change.
- The project references in other `.*proj` files

When the casing of a single project is fixed, the change may cascade to other project files that reference the problematic project. The `ProjectReference` element in the project file has a relative file system path to the problematic project and also captures its name. You can see this clearly in the screenshot you posted:

[image]